# Can I replace broken clips in a recessed light fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have discovered some of the remodel cans (Halo/Elite) that I had an electrician install have broken clips (the clips that hold the can to the drywall). Are these easy to replace or does the entire can need to be replaced? What would cause them to break? (e.g. sloppy installation, defective). Is it easy to unclip and remove the cans? I'd like to get my facts straight before I go back to the electrician.

Comment: What is broken, the can itself or the trim?

Comment: The clips that hold the can tight against the drywall. The black things on the outside of the can http://www.homedepot.com/buy/lighting-fans/recessed-lighting/halo/5-in-remodel-insulation-contact-airtite-recessed-housing-40841.html

Comment: How much would I need to spend to get clips that don't break? The Juno can, considered to be high-end, is only a few dollars more.

Comment: I imagine you'd have to call the manufacture to inquire about spare parts, though for the cost of the cans, just buy a new can and salvage parts from it. You could try taking it back to HD to exchange too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace the clips. They slide in from the inside and then get mooshed against the side to stay put. Just unmoosh the old ones, slide them out, and slide in the new ones.

Of course, that won't keep the new clips from busting on you.

Removing the cans is just as easy. Pop out the old clips, slip the can down through the hole, wiggle it sideways to pull the built-in box through, open that up and untwist the wires. You can then install whatever alternative can you'd like.

I recommend the Commercial Electric T91 LED disk light. It's a 6-in disk that can mount to a 4-in junction box that's at least 1-1/4 inches deep (or something reasonable like that). You should have no problem getting a good and sturdy 4 inch box. (It also screws into cans if you already have those.)

I'm getting ready to install 5 of those T91s in junction boxes on one side of a large room and 4 4-inch Halo LEDs in the 4-inch Halo remodel cans on the other side.

Comment: The T91s were discontinued in early 2013